# Cut using delimiter as number for a string in shell

Tags: shell, sh, cut

```
a="abc-ABC-3.2-def"
```

For the above mentioned variable, I need to cut so that i get all the string before occurrence of number.

Output expected after cut is,

```
 abc-ABC-
```

The number can be anything, Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $a | awk '{print $1}' FS=[0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash [strings](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919):

```
echo ${a%%[0-9]*}
```

%% means greedy pattern matching from the right, we match any digit (0-9) followed by some text (or nothing).